# Hibernate date field with a unique constraint on the day

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, date, annotations, constraints

I'm currently implementing a historical report store where users will store only 1 report per day. We're trying to apply unique constraints but we're struggling as the created date goes down to millisecond resolution. Is there anyway to apply a constraint to just the day of a Date field in Hibernate without having to drop down to apply the constraint directly in our underlying Postgres DB?

The code that doesn't work currently looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"createdDate", "name"})) 
public class Report {

  @Column
  private Date createdDate

  @Column   
  private String name;

  @Id   
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)   
  private Long id;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
on createdDate? I think that annotation will tell Hibernate to generate a Date column (instead of one holding a complete timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

You could

- Insert a index as proposed by StarShip3000 as a [database-object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object) in Hibernate mappings
- Add another property to the class which is private and mapped to the database to a unique field and returns only the date of creation. If you need the creation time as well, implement an empty setter.
- Map the field to a database datatype which only stores dates (I don't know postgres, but assume that there is such a data type). If you don't need the creation time, it's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hibernate, but you can create this constraint directly on the database table using good old straightforward SQL.

Such as:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_report_name_create_date ON report (name,date_trunc('day', create_date));



select date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');

RETURNS 2001-02-16 00:00:00

select date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 10:38:40');

RETURNS 2001-02-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: If your table doesn't already exist you could create the create_date as a DATE datatype as @Stefan Steinegger mentioned instead of TIMESTAMP. Then you would just create the unique index on the name and date column without needing the date_trunc function around the date.